# Why is a field not showing as an option in Combo box? Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I am working in Microsoft Access creating a form. When I go to enter a Combo box based on a table or query the field I want to use is not showing. When I go to either the query or even the table it's based on the field is clearly there and populated. The field is not frozen or hidden. I am looking to reference the "frequency" field but it does not show. I have attached pictures to illustrate the problem.

[Qry showing "frequency" field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNASY.png)

[Combo box not showing "frequency" field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIjMa.png)

Comment: Try to position field Picture as the last column in the query.

Comment: If you added the field in the query AFTER you created the combo, it will not be shown - it doesn't refresh. Delete the combo and start again.

Comment: This is odd. Available fields show for me regardless of position in relation to attachment field.